# Integer out of Range - Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, twitter

I'm working with the Twitter API in Django, using Tweepy.

I use this helperfunction to save tweets down, it works about 50% of the time, and throws a 'DataError: integer out of range' exception the rest of the time - this is currently caught in the code below and the erroring tweet logged (for later parsing!) but the time has come to fix it now.

```
def read_tweet(tweet_data, current_user):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('django')
    from coreapp.models import Tweet
    from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
    from django.db import DataError
    #We might get weird results where user has changed their details, so first we check the UID.
    try:
        #print "trying tweet_data.id"
        current_tweet =Tweet.objects.get(id=tweet_data.id)
        created=False
        return current_user, created
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    try:
        current_tweet, created = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(
        truncated=tweet_data.truncated,
        text=tweet_data.text,
        in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_data.in_reply_to_status_id,
        id=tweet_data.id,
        favorite_count=tweet_data.favorite_count,
        author = current_user,
        _json = tweet_data._json,
        source=tweet_data.source,
        retweeted=tweet_data.retweeted,
        coordinates = tweet_data.coordinates,
        entities = tweet_data.entities,
        in_reply_to_screen_name = tweet_data.in_reply_to_screen_name,
        id_str = tweet_data.id_str,
        retweet_count = tweet_data.retweet_count,
        in_reply_to_user_id = tweet_data.in_reply_to_user_id,
        favorited = tweet_data.favorited,
        user = tweet_data.user,
        geo = tweet_data.geo,
        in_reply_to_user_id_str = tweet_data.in_reply_to_user_id_str,
        lang = tweet_data.lang,
        created_at = tweet_data.created_at,
        place = tweet_data.place)
        return current_tweet, created
    except(DataError), e:
        try:
            current_tweet, created = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(
            text=tweet_data.text,
            id=tweet_data.id,
            author = current_user,
            _json = tweet_data._json,
            user = tweet_data.user,
            created_at = tweet_data.created_at,
                )
            return current_tweet, created

        except(DataError), e: 
            errormessage = {"errortweet": tweet_data._json}
            print errormessage
            logger.error(str(errormessage))
            return None, None
```

Models.py

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    truncated=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    text=models.TextField(max_length=140)
    in_reply_to_status_id=models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    id=models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    favorite_count=models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    _json = models.TextField()
    source=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    retweeted=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    coordinates = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    entities = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    in_reply_to_screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    id_str = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    retweet_count = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    in_reply_to_user_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    favorited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    retweeted_status = models.TextField()
    user = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) #User is a dictionary in the response; here we take a serialised version
    geo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    in_reply_to_user_id_str = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    possibly_sensitive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    in_reply_to_status_id_str = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    place = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

If I disable the last try/except so that it errors in django debug mode, I get the following traceback:

http://dpaste.com/1Y0BXXW

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/cursorsearch/surveillance/

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'coreapp',
 'silk',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/dev/als/coreapp/views.py" in cursor_search
  92.         current_tweet, created = read_tweet(tweet, current_user)
File "/Users/dev/als/coreapp/tools.py" in read_tweet
  173.         created_at = tweet_data.created_at,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get_or_create
  154.         return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get_or_create
  388.                     six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get_or_create
  380.                     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1511.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  898.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: DataError at /cursorsearch/surveillance/
Exception Value: integer out of range
```

As you can see, the fields in question are BigInts, so should be good for the larger twitter ids, as Twitter documentation indicates they need 64 bit signed, so we're covered off. 
I've also tried, in shell, explicitly converting to Long type, which makes no odds.  I've also covered off trying it with a different User model, which makes no difference (the User model has previously saved with no problem, and I can retrieve them through shell or queries as normal).

I used Silk to examine the SQL and the main difference i could see between a successful tweet save and an unsuccessful was that the SQL in the successful ones explicitly assigned NULL to the integer values (like 'in_reply_to_user_id'), etc - but that can't be it, surely?  If i'm saving without any assignation where Null=True is specified in the model, that should be ok.

Up to a day trying to fix this now. :)

Edit:  i've also just tried adding default=None to those fields, just in case, but that hasn't worked either, same error.

Second edit: 
An example of successfully used id would be 524539416799617024, an unsuccessful one would be 524539525209808896, so should be fine on that. I actually just tried doing it from command line with a previously saved tweet.id, and threw the same exception, so it's clearly something else - but I don't know what!

Further examples:  Successfully saved tweet ids - 524822288437633024, 524822389821939714
Failed tweet: 524822248499060736, 524823331368091648

I've tested these in command line by assigning 
u = User.object.get_or_create(id=id_from_tweet)
t = Tweet(id = 524823331368091648, user = current_user) then hitting t.save() - same error.
I've also checked the integers with just simply
a = -9223372036854775808, b = id, c = 9223372036854775808 and a < b < c comes out as True.

I've also explicitly forced the int to be Long before assigning it on command line, but doesn't make any difference either.

Final edit:  I didn't get a specific answer to this.  It seems like it might be related to the [JSON/SNowflake problem](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake) - where it gets munged as it gets parsed on the way.  As an intermittent fault, I'm not clearer on why some were fine and others not, and I'm not 100% sure if that's what caused it but it seemed likely.

Comment: Your successful id is invalid. It may be because the tweet was deleted. Do you have any other successful ids you could provide as examples?

Comment: Have added another couple above.

Comment: Well the common thread certainly seems to be whether or not in_reply_to_status_id and in_reply_to_user_id are None or not. None fails, and integer succeeds. The null=True should take care of allowing None values. So, maybe check that your model is being accurately reflected in your db structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked what the BigIntegerField class accepts? Make sure it can take ALL values being passed to it at initialization.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/):
class BigIntegerField([**options])
A 64 bit integer, much like an IntegerField except that it is guaranteed to fit numbers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.

Seems like NULL or None might not be acceptable... I see you had tried setting them to default zero in some of them, but not in all.

Comment: Yep - so, for example, doing it from command_line, an example of successful id would be 524539416799617024, an unsuccessful one would be 524539525209808896, so should be fine on that.  I actually just tried doing it from command line with a previously saved tweet.id, and threw the same exception, so it's clearly something else - but I don't know what!  Q updated accordingly.

Comment: Are all the unsuccessful ones over a certain number? Any successful ones over that number? Maybe one of the systems is 32bit and the integer is too large for it to handle. (Maybe Python is 64 bit so the BigIntegerField doesn't fail, but the DB is 32bit, or viceversa, etc). Otherwise there's got to be something in the code that takes the number out of range or gives a bad value.

Comment: Wait, I think it has to do with improper container for a 64bit integer, but I think the problem might be when you assign the model objects to regular python int variables. Are you sure the ints used are also big integers? How are you testing in console?

Comment: Added that to the q. :)